# equivalence of expressions in 1st order logic

Tags: first-order-logic

Is the followig two expressions equivalent ?
$$
\forall v : (P(v) \Rightarrow Q) \hspace{1cm} {\rm and} \hspace{1cm} (\exists v : P(v)) \Rightarrow Q
$$
My humble attempt is to interpert the quantification as conjunctions and disjunctions respectively and then distribute over the (reformed) implication, that is
$$
\forall v : (P(v) \Rightarrow Q) \iff (P(v_1) \Rightarrow Q)\wedge(P(v_2) \Rightarrow Q)\wedge\dots \iff \bigwedge_i (P(v_i) \Rightarrow Q)\\
(\exists v : P(v)) \Rightarrow Q \iff (P(v_1) \vee P(v_2) \vee \dots )\Rightarrow Q \iff (\bigvee_i P(v_i)) \Rightarrow Q
$$
which for two conjuncts is founded to be
$$
(P(v_1) \Rightarrow Q)\wedge(P(v_2) \Rightarrow Q) \\
\iff (\neg P(v_1) \vee Q)\wedge(\neg P(v_2) \vee Q) \\
\iff [(\neg P(v_1) \vee Q)\wedge\neg P(v_2)]\vee[(\neg P(v_1) \vee Q)\wedge Q] \\ 
\iff [(\neg P(v_1)\wedge\neg P(v_2))\vee(Q\wedge\neg P(v_2))]\vee[Q] \\
\iff [(\neg P(v_1)\wedge\neg P(v_2))\vee[Q] \\
\iff \neg( P(v_1)\vee P(v_2))\vee Q \\
\iff (P(v_1)\vee P(v_2)) \Rightarrow Q
$$
and for too many may be generalized to
$$
\bigwedge_i (P(v_i) \Rightarrow Q) \iff (\bigvee_i P(v_i)) \Rightarrow Q
$$
which if, I'm not mistaken, means the equivalence of the expressions with quantifiers above

Comment: Your proof for the case of $v_1$ and $v_2$ is fine. Note that, if you want to prove the generalized result, you can make the use of rules of inference. Are you familiar with rules of inference in first order logic?

Comment: @AirMike Unfortunately no. But despite that, is the generalized result true ?

Comment: Because you use the equiv $P \to Q$ with $\lnot P \lor Q$, a simpler proof will be: $∀v:(P(v) ⇒ Q) ⟺∀v: ¬(P(v) ∨ Q)$ and so on.

Comment: If I modify the second expression in the question to have instead of the implicaion an equivalence , are they going to be equivalent expresseions ?

Comment: I have to add sth to the question to explain wherefrom I got, I hope you take a look

Comment: @Physor I didn’t quite understood what parts of the Wikipedia page you are referring to, can you please be more clear, so I can take a look? Thank you

Comment: Axiom of Union https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory#5._Axiom_of_union and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_union#Formal_statement