# Mendelson, intro. to .math. log, Lemma 2.29, d)

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic

In Mendelson's book, Introduction to Mathematical Logic I put **Lemma** $2.29$, part $d$) in question. It reads
$$
\vdash\neg ( \mathscr{D}  \Rightarrow (\exists x)\mathscr{C} (x)) \iff (\exists y)( \mathscr{D}  \Rightarrow \mathscr{C} (y))
$$
I don't understand what "$\vdash$" is for, but let me rewrite it like this
$$
\neg ( D  \Rightarrow \exists x\ C (x)) \iff \exists y\ ( D  \Rightarrow C (y)) \tag{*}
$$
I have a big problem with the negation sign at the begining. I could "derive" other parts of the same **Lemma** $2.29$, e.g. $b$) [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3823563/equivalence-of-expressions-in-1st-order-logic) in simple way, call it intuitive. This part here is not all right. could check it please.

This is my attempt, assuming that $\exists y P(y)$ can be understood as $\bigvee_y P(y):= P(y_1) \vee P(y_2) \vee \dots$, but let us take two disjuncts. Starting with the LHS of (*)

$$
\exists y\ ( D  \Rightarrow P (y)) \\
\bigvee_y ( D  \Rightarrow P(y))\\
(D \Rightarrow P(y_1) \vee (D \Rightarrow P(y_2)) \\
(\neg D \vee P(y_1)) \vee (\neg D \vee P(y_2)) \\
\neg D \vee P(y_1) \vee \neg D \vee P(y_2) \\
\neg D \vee P(y_1) \vee  P(y_2) \\
\neg D \vee (P(y_1) \vee P(y_2)) \\
D \Rightarrow(P(y_1) \vee P(y_2)) \\
D \Rightarrow  (\bigvee_y P(y)) \\
D \Rightarrow  (\exists y\ P(y)) \\
$$
as you can see there is no $\neg$ at the end!. What is wrong ? Even in the 6th edition, **Lemma** $2.29$ was not changed.

The following image is from the 5th edition
[image: From the 5th edition]

Comment: $\vdash$ means: it is a theorem of *predicate calculus* i.e. the formula is derivable from logical axioms by way of Modus Ponens and Gen. See page 28.

Comment: nice, what else

Comment: And yes, the negation sign is a typo; see [PNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prenex_normal_form#Implication). In 4th edition (1997) the formula is typed correctly.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer